# Permanent redirection in asp.net when old page not exist?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

Hope you all are spending a great time in this forum. Today I joined this forum and come with a problem. My problem is that...

Recently i created a website and when I create its pages then 1 page name is misspell. Now I want to redirect this page to real page name. I am using this code:

```
<system.web>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="misspell url " type="UrlRedirection" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

This code is fine in local server but when I upload this code on server its show 500 internal server error.

Points:
•   We used godaddy hosting , IIS 7 .

Need help!

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Isn't a [rewrite rule](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template) what you need?

Answer (score 4):

Good news, you are using IIS7 and your GoDaddy hosting supports the UrlRewrite module:

- http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5443/microsoft-url-rewrite-module

This means you do the following:

1. Delete the `<httpHandler>` `<add />` that you have set up.
2. Find `<system.webServer>` in your web.config
3. Paste this in between the start and close tags:

Code:

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites" defaultValue="">
      <add key="/oldurl.aspx" value="/newurl.aspx" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RewriteMap Rule">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{StaticRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You can add as many of these rows as you like if you want to redirect several pages:

```
<add key="/oldurl.aspx" value="/newurl.aspx" />
```

I just double checked this on my server and it produces a 301 redirect (which is a permanent, seo friendly redirect).

Comment: Thanks for Replying but this code has same problem..

In local server it's working fine.But when i upload this code on server it showing same error 
**500 internal server error** . if You know any other soution of this problem please reply me asap.
 



Thanks..

Comment: the 500 internal server error is probably not related to this code then. Perhaps the web.config uses some other configuration item that is breaking the site.

Comment: Unfortunately debugging an error in the actual web.config generally seems to be a case of commenting out certain blocks, saving and retrying. I'd be interested to know if anyone has any better techniques.

Comment: you are right bro. I recheck my code and found error and now i solved out the problem ...

Comment: What in more detail did u do to fix it on the other server?

Comment: I don't know what other server you're referring to, we were only discussing an issue on a single server/website.